# Irreducibility of a family of polynomials coming from Fibonacci polynomials

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\{F_n(z)\,|\, n\geq 1\}$ be the Fibonacci polynomials, defined recursively by $F_1=1, F_2=z$ and $F_{n+2}=zF_{n+1}+F_n$. Now consider the polynomial
$$\varphi_{n,m}(z)=4-F_n^2F_m^2(z^2+3).$$
I would like to show that $\varphi_{n,m}(z)\neq f(z)f(-z)$ for any $f(z)\in\mathbb Z[z]$ for a large family of odd $n,m$. When $n=1$, $m=1$ or $n=m$, the polynomials do split as $f(z)f(-z)$, but in all other cases they appear to be irreducible. I used Mathematica to check all other pairs of odd $n,m$ less than $100,$ and they all are irreducible.

So my question is:

**Question:** *How can we prove that $\varphi_{n,m}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[z]$ for all odd $n,m$ where $n\neq m$ and, $n,m>1$?*

For example, the simplest cases are 
$$\varphi_{3,5}=1 - 25 z^2 - 80 z^4 - 126 z^6 - 106 z^8 - 48 z^{10} - 11 z^{12} - z^{14}$$
$$\varphi_{3,7}=1 - 43 z^2 - 227 z^4 - 569 z^6 - 787 z^8 - 645 z^{10} - 320 z^{12} - 
 94 z^{14} - 15 z^{16} - z^{18}$$
$$\varphi_{5,7}=1 - 55 z^2 - 405 z^4 - 1557 z^6 - 3440 z^8 - 4594 z^{10} - 3860 z^{12} - 
 2086 z^{14} - 724 z^{16} - 156 z^{18} - 19 z^{20} - z^{22}$$
Even if we can't show irreducibility, I would still be very interested in showing that $\varphi_{n,m}(z)$ cannot be factored as $f(z)f(-z)$ for an infinite family of odd pairs $n,m$.

Edit: In case anyone is curious about the context, this question arose in my joint paper with Vajira Manathunga, [The Conway polynomial and Amphicheiral knots](http://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04453). See the discussion following Proposition 3.13. Note also that Proposition 3.14 gives a sketch of the proof that the polynomials split in the $n=1$ and $n=m$ cases.

Comment: Have you proven that the splitting always occurs for (odd) $m=n$ and for $n=1$?

Comment: @MarkFischler: yes. $\varphi_{1,m}=f(z)f(-z)\in\mathbb Z[z],$ where $f(z)=F_{m+1}+F_m+F_{m-1}$ and $\varphi_{m,m}=f(z)f(-z)\in\mathbb Z[z]$, where $f(z)=
F_m^2+F_{2m}-2$.